# python docx to bold entire line on a bullet point on word

Tags: python, docx

I am trying to make an entire line bold on a bullet list. I have tried this:
`p=document.add_paragraph(str(dictionary[look]),style='List Bullet')`
 `p.add_run(str(dictionary[look])).bold=True`

but that adds two lines, one on a bullet and one bolded. Anyway to get a single full line on a bullet bolded?

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```py
p = document.add_paragraph(style='List Bullet')
p.add_run(str(dictionary[look])).bold = True
```

And it resulted in a single bold bullet.

I think `add_run` is adding a new section of content to the paragraph, whereas `add_paragraph` starts a new paragraph optionally with that string argument you specified as content. So it makes sense it would appear twice because first you start a paragraph with the string and then you add a second bold string. My approach starts with an empty paragraph and adds a single bold run.